# Resolve connection issue when calling a WCF service through windows 8 app

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8.1

I am trying to call a WCF service via a windows 8.1 app that I have created. But when I call it I get the exception:

> One or more errors occurred
>
> Unable to connect to the remote server
>
> There was no endpoint listening at http://theRequestedService.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.
>
> An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions [theIPAddress:thePortNumber]

I have reviewed the settings of the service and they seem to be okay and have checked to see if I can access it the following ways:

- access via browser (successful)
- access via console application (successful)
- run Fiddler4 and my windows 8 app (successful)
- access directly from the app (falied)

NB: I ran fiddler4 to try and get an error message that would lead me to the solution

I thought I may have altered a setting in my project, so created a fresh test project, but I get the same issue.

The exception messages seem self explanatory so why am I able to successfully connect via the other methods but not through the app? and what steps need to be taken to resolve this issue?

MY CONNECTION CODE (if this helps with solving the problem)

```
class ConnectionManager
{
    public static ConnectionStatus IsConnected()
    {
        ConnectionProfile connections = NetworkInformation.GetInternetConnectionProfile();

        ConnectionStatus result = (connections != null && connections.GetNetworkConnectivityLevel() == NetworkConnectivityLevel.InternetAccess) ? ConnectionStatus.NotSet : ConnectionStatus.NoInternet;

        if (result == ConnectionStatus.NotSet)
        {
            CommonFunctionsClient client = new CommonFunctionsClient();

            try
            {
                client.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.Binding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000);
                if (client.PingAsync().Result)
                    result = ConnectionStatus.Connected;
                else
                    result = ConnectionStatus.NoWCF;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
                //result = ConnectionStatus.NoWCF;
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}

public enum ConnectionStatus
{
    Connected,
    NoWCF,
    NoInternet,
    NotSet
}
```

Comment: Is the service running on localhost? IIRC in that scenario Windows 8 apps are constrained somehow.

Comment: I had it running locally and it was working fine. The issue has started after hosting it.

Answer (score 0):

For me to resolve this issue I downloaded HtmlAgilityPack
[HtmlAgilityPack found here from nuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack)

I guess the error was due to an issue with x-paths.

I admit this is far from a complete answer but it may help someone resolve their issue if they come across the same thing.

Hopefully someone could provide a reason this solution worked, or a better solution to this issue.